# ISCSI target mounted with different LUN number

Tags: centos, target, iscsi, zfs, openindiana

On a centOS host, I am able to discover my ISCSI targets from my SAN with this command :

`iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p IPOfMySan`

A login on a specified target from the result list of the previous command will be fine.

But when I check :

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/`

It's a real mess.

My target is online but appears several times with different LUN number, I have as much entry as the number of targets discovered.

> iqn.(..)-eb1ecece5792-lun-0 -> ../../sdb
>   
> iqn.(..)-eb1ecece5792-lun-1 -> ../../sdc
>   
> iqn.(..)-eb1ecece5792-lun-2 -> ../../sdd
>   
> iqn.(..)-eb1ecece5792-lun-3 -> ../../sde
>   
> iqn.(..)-eb1ecece5792-lun-4 -> ../../sdf
>   
> iqn.(..)-eb1ecece5792-lun-5 -> ../../sdg
>   
> iqn.(..)-eb1ecece5792-lun-6 -> ../../sdh
>   
> iqn.(..)-eb1ecece5792-lun-7 -> ../../sdi

How can I avoid this problem ?

Am I clear enough in my description ?

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: not sure that what you are looking for is possible. To may try to post your question to "serverfault" or "superuser".